# Example of asp.net core integration with azure devops via oAuth

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-devops

I'm trying to use oauth to facilitate integration from an asp.net core app and filing bugs in Azure DevOps.  I followed the guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops using the asp.net core 3.0 middleware to configure oauth.

When I hit a page that's been marked with [Authorize], it properly redirects me to the devops auth page with the scopes I've requested, but when I authorize, it redirects me back to my server but has the error:

`{"Error":"invalid_client","ErrorDescription":"Invalid client auth token."}`

I've confirmed I'm using the right endpoints and the right client secret in my config.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "ado";
        })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOAuth("ado", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "[AppId from devops]";
        options.ClientSecret = "[Client Secret from devops]";
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-ado");

        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize";
        options.TokenEndpoint = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token";

        options.Scope.Add("vso.identity");
        options.Scope.Add("vso.work_full");

        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "UserId");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "EmailAddress", ClaimValueTypes.Email);
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name");
    });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Configure:

```
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

The examples I found using oAuth with devops are from Asp.Net webforms, are there any for asp.net core?

(This is the full error)

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: BadRequest;Headers: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
Set-Cookie: VstsSession=%7B%22PersistentSessionId%22%3A%22f8e30b87-a6eb-470d-9ea2-ddf7b1f0dd84%22%2C%22PendingAuthenticationSessionId%22%3A%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%22%2C%22CurrentAuthenticationSessionId%22%3A%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%22%7D; domain=.visualstudio.com; expires=Mon, 16-Sep-2024 22:38:25 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-TFS-ProcessId: 98486e68-ccc8-4bc2-9907-f44cec26922a
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
ActivityId: b0088e1b-d2d0-4788-8328-d97aeeecb447
X-TFS-Session: b0088e1b-d2d0-4788-8328-d97aeeecb447
X-VSS-E2EID: b0088e1b-d2d0-4788-8328-d97aeeecb447
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:20b3930f-73dc-453a-b660-e3891d782eef
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Request-Context
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 9DC5A709B96D4D838858E4FC56797DE4 Ref B: WSTEDGE1017 Ref C: 2019-09-18T22:38:25Z
Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2019 22:38:24 GMT
;Body: {"Error":"invalid_client","ErrorDescription":"Invalid client auth token."};
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

Comment: Have you added `app.UseAuthentication();` on `Configure` function ?

Comment: Thanks, I added the configure section

Comment: @ScottFoster1000 was the issue fixed after added configure? You can posted this solution and mark it as answer for those who may encounter this problem too.

Comment: No, unfortunately that was just the configure section I already had.

Answer (score 0):

If your Post for the authorization code was done via url encoded query string, You can try getting it done via the **request body** instead. You can refer to a sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the parameters used in the OAuthHandler to exchange the authorization code for a token are different than those used in the Azure devops auth sample.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/OAuth/src/OAuthHandler.cs, line 179

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/master/OAuthWebSample/OAuthWebSample/Controllers/OAuthController.cs, line 74

You can work around this by creating your own handler that inherits from OAuthHandler and overrides the ExchangeCodeAsync method to use the paremeters from the sample.